# Is there a way to simplify this statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement

In C++ want to write something like this

```
int Answer;
if (Answer == 1 || Answer == 8 || Answer == 10)
```

and so on, is it any way to make code shorter without repeating variable always?

Comment: What you have written is actually legal C++ :) Unfortunately, Microsoft's C++ Compiler does not support `or`, so you'll have to replace it with `||` to increase compatibility.

Comment: i'm waiting for someone to post an obfuscated example that matches this specific example of 1, 8, or 10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
 switch (Answer) {
     case 1:    // fall through
     case 8:    // fall through
     case 10:
         // ... do something
         break; // Only need if there are other case statements.
                // Leaving to help in mainenance.
 }
```

Comment: :-) Remember that in C and C++ the case conditions MUST be constant!

Comment: Just because the OP didn't know about `switch`, I will comment that it is important to put `break;` at the end of each case, otherwise you will "fall through" to the next case labels

Comment: You should add a default. A switch that does not hit a case(or default) will crash the code.

Comment: @Nim, sorry for the misunderstanding. What I meant was if the OP wanted to add `case 11, case 12`, etc, there should be a break after `case 10`

Comment: @Martin are you sure? This is new for me... I was quite sure it worked without break and default. Just checked under VC and it works without break and default.

Comment: @ xanatos: I just checked my copy of the C standard n1124 (pub 2005). So you are correct this no longer causes it to crash. Note: checking something like this with a particular version of a compiler will not help you, especially if the behavior is undefined. Get a copy of the [standard:](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

Comment: @Steve314: with switch/case there's no need for braces, as it's really just a jump table.

Comment: @Steve314: To be pedantic you do need a copy the standard to check these things (as you will never remember everything that is UB). C++ inherits from C so checking case in this context is fine in either standard.

Answer (score 5):

For readability I'd encapsulate the logic in descriptively-named functions.  If, say, your answers are things with a particular color, and answers 1, 8, and 10 are green things, then you can write that logic as

```
bool ChoiceIsGreen(int answer)
{
    return (answer == 1 || answer == 8 || answer == 10);
}
```

Then your function becomes

```
if (ChoiceIsGreen(Answer))
{
    // offer some soylent green
}
```

If you have a lot of choices like this, I can see it getting hard to read if you have a lot of raw numbers all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

If and only if you need to optimise for code size manually, and Answer is guaranteed to be positive and less than the number of bits in an int, you might use something like

```
if ( ( 1 << Answer ) & 0x502 )
```

But normally you don't want to obscure your logic like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the values into a container and search the container.
Sounds like a `std::set` would be a wise choice:
  *if answer is in the set of (1, 8, 10) then do....*

Remember that a `std::set` must be initialized during run-time, unlike numeric constants or an array of numeric constants.  Before making any performance changes, first get the program working correctly, then profile **if necessary**, that is only if the program demands performance optimization.